# How can I host two or more web services on one HttpServiceHost?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I wrote a service which is a part of big project which provide a service itself. I do not want to write a composer class which implements both Contracts.

Right now it is like:

```
ServiceA: IServiceA
ServiceB: IServiceB
```

and in the host application:

```
var host = new HttpServiceHost(typeof(ServiceA), config, baseurl);
```

but I cannot do this:

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceB), new WSHttpBinding(), "ServiceB");
```

because ServiceA does not implement IServiceB.

I do not want to write the composer class implementing both interfaces and route them to instances as I cannot change the implementation of ServiceA. What should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add different endpoint using different binding (eg. `NetTcpBinding`). *But that's just dirty way around.*

So called "composer" class is how this problem is usually solved. However, I don't see how not being able to change `ServiceA` implementation introduces issue here...?

Create a simple wrapper class, with actual service logic still being in concrete, dedicated classes (you won't have to change anything). All this class will do would be **implement contract** and **delegate work** to proper implementators:

```
public class ComposedServices : IServiceA, IServiceB
{
    private IServiceA serviceA;
    private IServiceB serviceB;

    public ComposedServices(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA; 
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void SomeMetodFromA()
    {
        this.serviceA.SomeMethodFromA();
    }
}
```

`ComposedServices` sole purpose of existance is to overcome technical restrictions - itself alone, it brings no value and should containg virtually no logic.

Comment: I don't want to change the serviceA, as it will be used for other purposes. The serviceB is kinda additional service that I am providing.